Running apt-get update in Debian Docker container hangs on installing bookworm
This is probably the strangest error I've run into.
So I'm running a Wikibase Docker setup on a Windows machine. The Docker containers are all Debian OS.
In order to install some packages upon setting up the series of Docker containers, I run a very simple:
apt-get -y update

Starting yesterday, this command starting hanging on:
Get:4 http://deb.debian.org/debian bookworm/main amd64 Packages [8788 kB]

I thought this was an error with Docker, so I documented it here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78836358/wait-for-an-apt-get-command-in-a-bash-script-called-by-docker-exec-to-finish-bef. Weirdly enough, it was only happening when running the bash script. If I ran the command in shell, it ran fine, no issues.
Then, all of a sudden, the issue stopped happening at all this morning. Now, this evening, it's back with a vengeance. I've tried:

Using mirrors (I've tried multiple... no dice)
Updating DNS
Adding retries
Increasing verbosity to see if there are any errors (there are none)
Checking the network connection using ping/curl (it appears to be fine inside the Docker container; all the mirrors return 200)

And yet it still hangs on:
Get:4 http://ftp.de.debian.org/debian bookworm/main amd64 Contents (deb) [11.6 MB]

Or
Get:6 http://deb.debian.org/debian-security bookworm-security/main amd64 Packages [170 kB]

Etc.
What is going on? Even a clue would be super helpful at this stage! I can only imagine it may be some sort of firewall issue or something? But then why would it work when run on the command line but not in a script? And why would it function sometimes but not other times?
UPDATE 1:
Okay... so this only seems to happen when I'm on my home wifi? I have not had this problem at all when at work today, but it's started up just now as I've gotten home from work. Would that have something to do with it?

It could be because of the IP range of the home network vs the IP range of the docker container. Can you confirm a) this is a container (not docker build) b) what is the ip range of your home network (eg 192.168.0.x) and what is the ip range of the docker network the container is on? If you are unsure you can post the ip address of the container and the of address of your laptop.

This is a container (it's instantiated using docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml -f docker-compose.extra.yml up -d). The container's IP address is 172.18.0.5 (so the range is probably 172.18.*). Unfortunately I'm at work so I can't get the range of home network but I'll post when I get back from the office.

@PhilipCouling WAIT. It's started happening at work too now. Checked the IP of the container and sure enough now it's 192.168.16.6. How do I modify the https://github.com/wmde/wikibase-release-pipeline/blob/main/deploy/docker-compose.yml to keep that from happening?
